# How to post a form from GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I am trying to POST a form to a 3rd-party web server.

The form is like this:

```
<form method=post action="http://www.domain.com/path/page.do?id=18&localeCode=en-us">
<input type="submit" name="FILTER:name=init" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I load this HTML into a browser and submit the form, the correct page is returned by the web server. If I submit it from Swift using Alamofire all is well.

But on App Engine, using urllib2 or urlfetch a different HTML page is returned.

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
page = urlfetch.fetch(
    url="http://www.domain.com/path/page.do?id=18&localeCode=en-us",
    payload={"FILTER:name=init" : "Submit"},
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    deadline=30)
```

For the payload I've tried encoding name=init as name%3Dinit but without any further success.

Comment: have you tried spoofing a user-agent string? I don't think urlfetch has a very good one, maybe it's being rejected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to urlencode your payload dict manually before passing to `urlfetch.fetch`. See the example from the docs below.

```
import urllib

from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

form_fields = {
  "first_name": "Albert",
  "last_name": "Johnson",
  "email_address": "Albert.Johnson@example.com"
}
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
    payload=form_data,
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```